# insert a new row before and after currently selected row in wpf datagrid

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, row

I am using WPF datagrid. I need to insert the new row before and after the currently selected row. How can I do that?

Is there any straight way?

Comment: If you are binding the ItemSource to an ObservableCollection then modifying the collection would do the trick. 
Can you share the code that you have tried?

Comment: I tried to play with ControlTemplate of data grid but was not successful.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have a grid bound to something like an `ObservableCollection` with a SelectedItem property, something like this:
`<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">`.

So, in your view model or code-behind you can do this:

```
int currentItemPosition = Items.IndexOf(SelectedItem) + 1;
if (currentItemPosition == 1)
    Items.Insert(0, new Item { Name = "New Item Before" });
else
    Items.Insert(currentItemPosition - 1, new Item { Name = "New Item Before" });

Items.Insert(currentItemPosition + 1, new Item { Name = "New Item After" });
```

Here's a full example, I just used a blank WPF project.
Code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>
            {
                new Item {Name = "Item 1"},
                new Item {Name = "Item 2"},
                new Item {Name = "Item 3"}
            };

            DataContext = this;
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }

        public Item SelectedItem { get; set; }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            int currentItemPosition = Items.IndexOf(SelectedItem) + 1;
            if (currentItemPosition == 1)
                Items.Insert(0, new Item { Name = "New Item Before" });
            else
                Items.Insert(currentItemPosition - 1, new Item { Name = "New Item Before" });

            Items.Insert(currentItemPosition + 1, new Item { Name = "New Item After" });
        }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="DataGridTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Content="Add Rows" Click="Button_Click_1" />
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```